# Type enforcing input field

Tags: wicket

I am building a form with variable input fields. How the form is actually set-up (which fields and which types) is read from a database. To do this I would be using Panels, since there are also several labels per input field. The panels are then being displayed in a ListView.

When doing this, I do not like the idea to create a different panel which different markup files for each type of input (text, radio, checkbox,...), since TextField etc. check for the type set in the markup.

Is there an input field that does not read the type from markup, but supports all/some input types? Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: Did you take a look at fragments?

Comment: Surely you can just create placeholder markup inside the panel, which would be replaced with another panel which would hold only the input?

Comment: You could override the markup and attributes in `onComponentTag()`.